# How can I kick off an event if the user doesn't type anything for a set period of time? Set a timer and start it with the text changed event?

Tags: sql, vb.net

vb.net is the language. 
More in depth description is we have a text box where the user types in a set #. It can be anywhere from 1-3 digits, so i can't use text length to kick off the event. Right now, how the old coder had it programmed is this: The text changes, query the db to see if that set has been used and display a message to the user. This is causing way too many db queries; ie, type 1 (db query), type 1 again (another db query), hit backspace (db query), etc. I looked at his code and its 3 different db functions that happen, so what i think would be better would be to have the user input the final set number (you can tell when they're done typing by the lag time between entering. Then you do 1 db query.

Comment: Is acting only after the Enter key is pressed or a button is clicked out of discussion?

Comment: What Jimi said. What's wrong with a good old "submit" button?